# Location and changing category page loop in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, hook

I'm trying to use [this plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-highlights/) to add product highlights in the shop category loop in WooCommerce.

While the plugin works nicely with Astra and Storefront (highlights shown above "add to cart" button), the highlights are shown post "add to cart" for the site using [UXThemes Flatsome theme](https://flatsome3.uxthemes.com/).

Because the plugin works nicely in Astra and Storefront, I gather Flatsome somehow alters the loop / hooking for products shown in the shop / archive page.

**My question:** How do I go about debugging and figuring out exactly where Flatsome drops the ball?  I really need the highlihts to be shown before the add-to-cart button. You can see a staging / [testpage here](https://staging.maling.shop/?product_cat=god-maling-til-badevaerelse):

Right now I'm sifting through the theme layout and loop php files, and not getting any wiser.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You can use a plugin like [Show Hooks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-hooks/) or [Simply Show Hooks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simply-show-hooks/). What it does is give you a simpler way to see these hooks by displaying them in-line on the page that you are on. All that’s left to do then is copy the hook you need, and paste it in to your add_action and add_filter functions

Comment: Thanks for the two suggestions. I didn't know about those two plugins.

Unfortunately they dont seem to break down the WooCommerce parts too well yet (https://snipboard.io/tAcwBe.jpg). 

But it might just help me locate the code. Guess I have a long night ahead of me.